# Serialization of a class inside the class

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm currently trying to make a class `Singleton` that have a `serialize` method. The objective is to serialize `Singleton` in its own function. Is there any way to serialize a class inside this class ?

Here is a sample of what i tried :

```
public void serialize() {
    Singleton commit = this.getInstance();

    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new Config().getDataFile());
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(commit);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to commit database changes.");
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
```

And the stack trace below :

```
Unable to commit database changes.
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.cuistot.data.Singleton
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
    at [...].Singleton.serialize(Singleton.java:50)
    [...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your class implement `Serializable`?

Looking at the [source code for](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.java#ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0%28java.lang.Object%2Cboolean%29) `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0`, it throws `NotSerializableException` if the object is not a `Serializable`.